# N-Tier Application With Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, n-tier-architecture

I develeop an n-tier application with ASP.NET MVC. I can to switch my DAL another technologies. (ADO.NET, Oracle, MySQL etc..) But firstly i use ADO Entity Framework. But how should i code relation's in my entities? For example i have a Product class and it's relation a Category class. (Or i save just CategoryId in my Product entity??) i use in my view as product.Category.CategoryName() if i use EF but i think it's wrong approach for n-tier architecture. What's your suggest for this subject.

```
//Entities
public class Product(){
    public int ProductId{get;set;}
    public string ProductName{get;set;}

    //id or class relation? which one???
    public int CategoryId{get;set;}
    public Category Category{get;set;} //This works just Entity Framework of course
}

public Category(){
    public int CategoryId{get;set;}
    public string CategoryName{get;set;}
}


//in my view 
<p>
@Product.Category.CategoryName //I think it's not right approach for n-tier application? Pls suggest.
</p>
```

Comment: http://ntieref.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

I generally include the foreign keys in my entities. You can also include the related `Category` entity as a property in your `Product` class, for scenarios such as presenting in views as you have mentioned above.

One common way to handle related entities is to apply the `virtual` keyword to them, allowing for lazy or eager loading of the related entity. This way, you can perform CRUD operations on the `Product` class, and can assign the `Category` (via CategoryId) without needing the entire `Category` entity for the Category property. Then, you can choose to include relations in queries in which you may need them.

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId {get;set;}
    public string ProductName {get;set;}

    //id or class relation? both!
    public int CategoryId {get;set;}

    public virtual Category Category {get;set;}
}
```

Eager loading example:

```
db.Products.Include(p => p.Category).ToArray();

<p>
@Product.Category.CategoryName 
</p>
```

Comment: Virtual also allows change-tracking, right?  It works because EF generates a new class definition inheriting from yours at runtime and overrides all the virtual properties.

Answer (score 0):

You should separate out your Database logic from your front end stuff. Check out [Generic Unit Of Work and Repositories](http://genericunitofworkandrepositories.codeplex.com) for a good example of using `UnitOfWork` and `Repository` pattern.

Use DTOs, Views, or otherwise flatten objects before sending them down, or at least don't lazy load them. [AutoMapper](https://automapper.codeplex.com/) is very useful for helping with creating dtos / non-db objects.